# Is there a way to point to the code where the error happened in Rust?

Tags: error-handling, rust

I have the line and file in which an error happened using the `line!` and `file!` macros respectively. The Rust compiler is able to point to exactly where the cause of the error in the source code happened. Is there a way to point to a specific area in the code where the `line` = `line!` and the `file`= `file!`?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "point to"? If you have the file and line, what else are you hoping to get?

Comment: I would like to point to the exact code in which the error is happening. For example: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=e70d4354c828ab48e320272c294c2f6f shows where the error is emitted. Its because of the `}`. I would like to produce a similar compiler error.

Comment: Please be more specific. What error? A `Result`? Or a `panic`? Do you mean at compile time you want to print an error, or at runtime? This question is very unclear.

Comment: Please provide an example that shows what you mean, what you tried so far, and why it does not produce the result you expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not really clear what you are trying to do, but I think you are looking for crates that can format error messages like the Rust compiler, for example:

- [`codespan-reporting`](https://crates.io/crates/codespan-reporting)
- [`annotate-snippets`](https://crates.io/crates/annotate-snippets)
- [`codemap`](https://crates.io/crates/codemap)

or you might take a look at [the source code for error reporting in the the Rust compiler](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/tree/master/compiler/rustc_errors/src), but it uses its own module which is not usable from outside the compiler itself.

Answer (score 0):

In `Visual Studio Code` you can hold `Ctrl` and click on the line number in the panic and it will jump to the line in the editor.

For example when you run your program in the integrated terminal you might get:

```
thread 'main' panicked at 'explicit panic', src/main.rs:27:5
                                                 ^
                                                 |
                                     CLICK HERE -/
```